# How to get google account contacts throught dotnetopenauth

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

I would like to send invitations once the user login in my site throught dotnetopenauth.
When the user login, i like to get the user list, and allow user to select wish of them will receive the invitation to join my site.
My question is how to get user contacts mails.
Regards.

Comment: What is your website built in? How are users logging in (username + password combo or OpenID or. . )? We need more detail to help answer your question!

Answer (score 2):

This is something that you can gain through calls to Provider's API (for Google that "Google Contacts Data API"), so I assume DotNetOpenAuth does not do that for you!

e.g. for Google look at [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#retrieving_without_query)
for Yahoo that' [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/),...